# django:error with the custom inclusiong_tag, error info:Invalid block tag

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a custom inclusion_tag in django.

Following the example on http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

I'm just writing

```
from django import template
from libmas import models

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('records.html')
def display_records(book_id):

    book = models.book.objects.get(id__exact=book_id)
    records = models.objects.filter(books=book)[0:10]

    return {'records':records}
```

But I'm getting a

```
Invalid block tag: 'libmas_tags'
```

error in ie .

'records.html' file:

```
{% for record in records %}
<blockquote>{{record.id}}</blockquote>
{% endfor %}
```

my other html file is :

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% libmas_tags %}

{% block after_field_sets %}

{% if object_id %}
{% display_records object_id %}
{% endif %}

{% endlock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in your template. Its calling `{% libmas_tags %}`. Have you created template tags called libmas_tags? If so you might need to change it to

```
{% load libmas_tags %}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `libmas_tags`? The tag you have defined is called `display_records`, and that's what you should be calling in your template. If the tags file is called libmas_tags, you'll need to load that first as czarchaic points out.

Comment: libmas_tags is a file named libmas_tag.py. Now i modified:load libmas_tag as crarchaic.but i also get a new error:'libmas_tags' is not a valid tag library: Could not load template library from django.templatetags.libmas_tags, cannot import name models